# Unable to get customer id value

Tags: opencart-3

i have an opencart application and it is working fine in all the browsers except for IE11.
We could get the customer id through $this->customer->getId(); 
I am unable to get the customer id from session in IE11. what could be the problem? how can i resolve that.

Comment: i think your customer is not logged in. first fall you can login after check it.

Answer (score 0):

**[ For Customer ID ]**

Actually this is not a problem. You need to customer_id with customer logged in.

If customer logged out customer_id is 0.

You can see following code:

```
if ($this->customer->isLogged()) {

$data['customer_id'] = $this->customer->getId();

}
```